# Managing a great number of reports

Tags: qgis, reports

In a project I have about 20 different reports. In the report manager, the only presentation seems to be alphabetical order.
Is there any feature or parameter, or plugin that could help manage those reports more easily, with for exemple possibility to group some of them together, like a treeview, one or multiple level?
The problem also occurs when developping, when you want to keep previous versions of reports, the time to be happy with what you have done

Comment: AM I the only guy working with several reports ????